# In Scala 3, how can I write a method that returns some sort of Tuple depending on arguments?

Tags: scala, types, tuples, scala-3

I'm trying to write a method that combines higher types into new higher types using tuples. Say I have a type `Foo[X]`, then I want something like:

```
trait Foo[X]:
  def +(y: Foo[Y]) = <tuplify X and Y>
```

If `X` is already a `Tuple`, I want this method to return `Foo[Tuple.Append[X, Y]]`. If `X` is not a `Tuple`, I want it to return `Foo[(X, Y)]`.

I've tried to figure out a way to do this, but, unfortunately, I'm not having much luck. Is this even possible? The things I've considered and tried are match types and given conversions, but no matter what I do, the types don't match up somewhere, so I'm starting to worry that I'm on a wild goose chase.